# CypressError: Timed out retrying: You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object

Tags: jquery, chai, cypress

Using Cypress, I want to know whether the title of the page is correct. I am taking an example of Google homepage here 
I am using following command:

```
cy.title().should('have.value','google')
```

but I am getting an error:

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object.

The `chai-jQuery assertion` you used was:

> value

The invalid subject you asserted on was:

> Google

To use chai-jQuery assertions your subject must be valid.

This can sometimes happen if a previous assertion changed the subject.
...........

Can anybody tell the reason for this

Comment: Though when I am using         cy.title().should('eq',title), it is working fine

Comment: Different assertiions expect different objects. `title()` yields the title as string. But `have.value` maybe expects an JQuery object. So the answer Hardik mentioned my work oru you also can use `cy.title().should(t => expect(t).to.eq("test"))`